# Burnination: [beautifier] needs to be beautified

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

All of these tag pretty much about tool requests. We've got:

- [beautifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beautifier) - 100 questions, almost entirely tool requests
- [beautify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beautify) - 39 questions, almost entirely tool requests
- [beautification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beautification) - 26 questions, almost entirely tool requests
- [code-beautifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-beautifier) - 20 questions, almost entirely tool requests
- [php-beautifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-beautifier) - 9 questions, some of them are about [this tool](https://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Beautifier) which is fine but others of them are about how to beautify PHP in general [like this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392324/a-php-beautifier-formatter-pretty-printer) which is not so fine.

  - Should we keep a tag around when the tool has so few questions?
- [js-beautify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/js-beautify) - 17 questions, most seem to be about support for the tool itself, which is fine.

  - **DO NOT BURNINATE**

Let's close all the tool requests and then burn the tags.

[image: Beautiful fire]

Comment: Pretty fire.  If I had a flame thrower that shot that out I would spend all day burninating things.

Comment: You haven't really said why this is such a bad tag. Questions about code-beautification seem to be on-topic, because these are actions/tools that programmers use. I would rather close/delete bad questions and retag other to a new tag [code-beautification].

Comment: @ArtjomB. It's because they're all tool requests...

Comment: @durron Ok, so close the tool requests and see what remains then?

Comment: @ArtjomB. "How do I beautify my code" is a tool request. I don't really see any way for this to be on topic unless it's about a particular tool like [tag:uncrustify] or [tag:js-beautify], in which case the question should have that particular tag. No one is an expert on [tag:beautify], and it cannot stand alone as a tag.

Comment: Only [140 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beautifier+or+beautify+or+code-beautifier+or+beautification+or+php-beautifier) in total. That should be quick.

Comment: I was hoping for jokes about concealer but the image more than makes up for the lack of make-up puns.

Comment: I thought for a second it said "... needs to be [beatified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatification)". I doubt anybody wants that.

Comment: @BSMP Don't you mean "the image does more than make up for the lack of puns?"

Comment: @ssube - I've actually heard it phrased both ways: it "more than makes up for" and it "does more than make up for".

Comment: @ssube the picture itself is a pun.  "Beauti-fire"

Comment: @ryanyuyu that's so meta... oh wait.

Answer (score 10):

**Current Status**

- [beautifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beautifier) - **Burned**, all off-topic deleted, except 6 with the highest views/votes.
- [beautify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beautify) - **Burned**, any off-topic questions moved to [beautifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beautifier)
- [beautification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beautification) - **Burned**, any off-topic questions moved to [beautifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beautifier)
- [code-beautifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-beautifier) - **Burned**, any off-topic questions moved to [beautifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beautifier)

Comment: Additional burnination completed.